What does the n_unique value mean, when skimming list variables?
I do not understand the meaning of the n_unique value in skim about list variables:
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)

skim(starwars)

The following is part of the result, about the three list variables in the dataset:

Now, there are 10 different vehicles in the dataset, so it makes sense that n_unique is 11 (including the null case of Star Wars characters not using any vehicle). Characters can use from a min of zero vehicles (min_length) to a max of two different vehicles (max_length) all along the movies.
There are also 16 starships, and characters can use from zero to five different starships, so all makes sense.
However, there are only seven movies. So, n_unique should be 7 and not 24. Also, it is true that a character can make an appearance in a minimum of one movie (min_length) to a max of all the seven movies (max_length).

There are 7 values for individual films, but there are 24 unique elements if you compare the list elements between themselves.
For example if the first element is [The Phantom Menace, Revenge of the Sith] and the second element is [The Phantom Menace] then the two elements are different.
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)

# Count unique individual films
starwars$films |> 
  unlist() |> 
  unique() |> 
  length()
#> [1] 7

# Count unique list elements
starwars$films |> 
  unique() |> 
  length()
#> [1] 24


Thank you, I imagined something like this, but the coincidence about the vehicles and star ships put me in the wrong track. (Also, I would find it more useful to know about the unique values instead of about unique combinations of values!)

Depends on the context, sometimes it's useful to compare list elements between them. You could also unnest the list columns if you wanted to compute the number of unique values.
